# angular/rxjs object of behaviour subjects dont return the value

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I have a store service which contains an object with behaviour subjects so the store can grow and shrink easily. However for some reason using this approach i am unable to get the value from the BehaviourSubject as i usually would, using the .value accessor.

I can subscribe to the subject as usual and the result is correct.

```
  private listStore: any = {};


  public getList<T>(key: string): GraphResponse<T> {

    if (this.listStore[key]) {
      return this.listStore[key].value; <--- This returns null event when there is a value there
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }


  public list$<T>(key: string): Observable<T> {
    if (!this.listStore[key]) {
      this.listStore[key] = new BehaviorSubject<T>(null);
    }
    return this.listStore[key].asObservable(); <-- Subscribing to this at the same time works fine
  }
```

I have tried adding a timeout to test if it was possible the setter was slower than the getter, and it still returns null.

The console shows the subjects are populated as you would expect:

> categories: BehaviorSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0),
>   closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …} entities:
>   BehaviorSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false,
>   isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}

An example using the object above:

I have this object currently in my store:

```
let store = {
      test: new BehaviorSubject('testing 1 2 3'),
      another: new BehaviorSubject('another test!')
    }
```

Now, if I do:

store.test.subscribe().... it works fine and I can get the value

However, doing:

store.test.value returns null

This has only ever happened by having an object of behaviour subjects

Comment: not clear what you're trying to accomplish here. draw up a blitz or put in some specific example of how you're populating and accessing... as a note, the value getter in a behavior subject is supposed to be a "last resort" type option and often means you're doing something wrong

Comment: I am simply trying to get the value using the .value method from a an object containing behaviour subjects as displayed above. I can subscribe and get the value perfectly fine, however actually calling the '.value' method returns null even if there is a behavour subject - I'll ed my answer with an example

Comment: your bug doesn't reproduce, which is why you need more details... you're doing something else wrong and looking in the wrong place: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-amejdx?file=index.ts